# Can I use a string variable in document.getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

here is my code:

```
function figureSelector () {
    document.getElementById("rook").onclick = function  () {
        curr = '"rook"';
    };
};

function moveLine(){
    document.getElementById("upButton").onclick = function() { 
            document.getElementById(curr).style.top = document.getElementById(curr).offsetTop - getPix() * 62  + "px"; 
            counter= counter + getPix();
    };
```

I want to write an universal function for a chess piece to move. All I want is, when one clicks the chess piece, and then presses the up button, it must go up.

Comment: did you try it?..you can use it

Comment: Looks like this should work. Where are you having problems?

Comment: You can use a variable as the argument to any function. That's just how functions work -- they don't care where the argument comes from.

Comment: You should define `curr` outside those functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Just use

```
curr = 'rook';
```

(without the extra quotes)

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can use String variable:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="name" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:red"></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
var b = 'name';
document.getElementById(b).innerHTML = 'none';
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s5fJY/)

Answer (score 1):

You can even do stuff like this:

```
function mark(yy)  {
    for (var ii = 0; ii < 7; ii++ )  {
        if (  ii == yy )  {
            document.getElementById("b"+ii).style.fontWeight = "bold";
         }
...
```

But be careful of your loop limits to be sure you have a matching id. I just spent hours trying to figure out why `("b"+ii)` was getting error and finally realized that the error was being caused by exactly that. duh...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Mate, you can.

You can use a variable as the argument for any function. That's just how functions work -- they don't care where the argument comes from. You should define curr outside those functions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).